# Dynamic PHP child class name

Tags: php, oop

I've a really easy Php question.

Is the following possible:

```
$foo = 'bar';
Class $foo extends Object
{
...
}
```

I believe any OOP developer will have an idea about what I wish to accomplish. Thanks in advance for any hints.

UPDATE: Sometimes you would want to have the script's filename as its own classname (of course you'll have to prefix the classname to minimize collission). Also... without using eval(). I should have written the code as:

```
$cls = 'MyCls' . basename(__FILE__);
Class $cls extends Object
{
...
}
```

Comment: I am an OOP developer and I have no clue what you are trying to do. What you show is impossible. Clarify the question and we might be able to help you achieve whatever it is you are trying to do.

Comment: @Gordon - `eval("class $foo extends Object {})";` not impossible, but ugly as hell. And I also have no clue what this is for @Arlene Capili.

Comment: I've no idea why anyone would want to have dynamic class names, maybe you should present the problem you're having rather than trying to solve it the wrong way.

Comment: Why do you want such a functionality?

Comment: Who upvotes those answers and the question? Please stop suggesting they are useful when the question can only be answered with a crystal ball right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what your specific requirements are, however, I think you are going the wrong way about it. Rather than trying to create the class name based on the file name, why not use [`__autolod()`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) to load whatever the class you like and your code will know how to find it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about the autoload function. I didn't know about it until today.

Answer (score 5):

you could do something like:

```
// First define the Object class
class Object
{
}

// This will be the template class
$classDef = <<<TEXT
Class __MY_CLASS_NAME__ extends Object
{
}
TEXT;

// This will generate a class based on the given template
function generateClass($name, $classDef)
{
    eval(str_replace('__MY_CLASS_NAME__', $name, $classDef));
}

// Now use it altogether
generateClass('Something', $classDef);
$a = new Something;
var_dump($a);
```

EDIT: I agree with other people comments.. dont know what you want to do and sure is ugly, but ... there you go..

Answer (score 3):

Look into [class_alias](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.class-alias.php). First you create a class with a fixed name which extends Object as required. Then you create the dynamic alias.